# How to access private BitBucket repo in cloudfoundry app (Deploy ssh key before composer)

Tags: bitbucket, cloud-foundry, ssh-keys, swisscomdev

I searched several hours in the net and by try & error, but I don't get it:

How can I use private BitBucket repos in the composer.json for an app pushed to a cloud foundry environment?

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:blabla/blabla.git",
    "reference": "package"
  }
]
```

Problem is, that I need to setup public authentication (ssh key) BEFORE the composer in the cloud foundry startup is startet.

The .ssh folder has to be $HOME/../.ssh which is out of the app folder, so I cannot push the keys directly.
I found, that with bash scripts in .profile.d I could do some "mv" commands, but these bash scripts are run AFTER composer.

```
mkdir ./../.ssh
mv ./preprocess/ssh/id_rsa ./../.ssh/id_rsa
mv ./preprocess/ssh/id_rsa.pub ./../.ssh/id_rsa.pub
mv ./preprocess/ssh/known_hosts ./../.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 600 ./../.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ./../.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 644 ./../.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 700 ./../.ssh
```

There is a pre-install-cmd for composer itself, but even then, the keys don't get recognized.

```
"scripts": {
   "pre-install-cmd": "sh ./preprocess/pre-install-cmd.sh"
}
```

How is this properly done? Are there some special hook scripts? Do I have to add something after placing the ssh folder?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Putting your SSH private key into a git repo and in the hands of 3rd party provider (when uploading the App to CF) is a bad idea - don't do it!

The php-buildpack that is used when pushing PHP apps to CF supports composer with private registries in a secure way, but unfortunately only for Github at the moment:

It works by obtaining a Github OAuth Key first and providing it to the stager using `cf set-env`, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/composer.md#supply-a-github-token

Bitbucket also offers OAuth tokens, but support by composer arrived just some days ago: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5055
So it is not supported by the php-buildpack yet, but I assume it will be soon.

You are not the only one with this problem: [How to access private BitBucket repo in cloudfoundry app (Deploy ssh key before composer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420018/how-to-access-private-bitbucket-repo-in-cloudfoundry-app-deploy-ssh-key-before)
- it is about heroku, but applies also to CF since they have compatible buildpacks.

**Solution for now:**
If I interpret the doc correctly, you should be able to package the dependencies locally by using `composer install` and push the whole app with dependencies:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/composer.md#vendoring-dependencies